# array of threads creation in c

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have created two array of threads using POSIX thread.There are two thread functions student and teacher. My sample program is given below. I have a small problem which I have commented out in the code . I have written a thread join function at the last of main function. Is it okey or is there anything wrong in writing it in this way?

Sample code fragment:

```
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread[25];
    int i;
    int id1[25];   //for students
    int id2[6];   //for teachers

    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
          id1[i]=i;
          id2[i]=i;
          pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,student,(void*)&id1[i] );

          if(i<6)
          {
             pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,teacher,(void*)&id2[i]);
          }
   }



  for (i=0;i<25;i++)
  {
    pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);  //problem in this line
  }

 return 0;
```

}

Comment: Besides the problem with the variable, what is the problem you're having? Can you please be more specific? Or are you only wondering if you can do the join call there?

Comment: edited.now check it@cad

Comment: I just wanted to make 25 threads for students and 6 for teachers and at last waiting for all of them to close before closing main. Is there anything wrong here? @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: this line: `id2[i]=i;` will cause undefined behaviour when 'i' is greater than 5 because the `id2[]` is only 6 entries long and when 'i' is greater than 5, the value will be written past the end of the array.

Answer (score 6):

```
      pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,student,(void*)&id1[i] );

      if(i<6)
      {
         pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,teacher,(void*)&id2[i]);
      }
```

For `i<6`, the value in `thread[i]` for `student` is overwritten by later `pthread_create()`, which makes 6 threads leaked. 6 joinable threads remains running when `main()` is about to return.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that there should really be an if-else there somewhere.

Comment: I just wanted to create 25 threads for students and 6 for teachers simultaneously. Is there anything wrong there? Please help me rectify it @timrau

Comment: @user5404604 Then why not do it with two loops? One for the teachers and one for the students? And of course use different arrays for the thread identifiers.

Comment: can you please clarify what is the main difference between making two different arrays and in my case. I am confused @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: @user5404604 In your case, the array of `pthread_t` has size 25 which means that you can store a maximum of 25 pthreads in it. But you create 36 pthreads, leading to the first 6 being leaked as mentioned in this answer.

Comment: @user5404604 When you have a single array for the thread ids, you use `thread[0]` for the first student thread, then you use `thread[0]` for the first teacher thread as well. Array elements are like single variables, and they can only store a single value. When you use the same array element for both threads then you loose the first value.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that your problem is in the end when joining threads, but in the beginning when threads are started.

First of all, `id2[i]=i` might give a segfault unless that statement is moved to within the check that `i<6`.

Next, overwriting the same `&thread[i]` within the if-statement which was already created before the if-statement means that you have lost control of 6 student threads, those will not be joined at the end.

Answer (score 2):

One of the approach to avoid the problem of undefined behavior due to id2[i]=i and also the issue of number of threads left without joining at end can be by having separate array for teacher/student coupled with appropriate changes in creation/joining procedure.

You can have separate array of pthread_t for student and teacher as below :

```
pthread_t thread_teacher[6];
pthread_t thread_student[25];
```

Accordingly, the update in creation and joining procedure for covering both student and teacher can be as below :

```
for(i=0;i<25;i++)
{
    id1[i]=i;
    pthread_create(&thread_student[i],NULL,student,(void*)&id1[i] );
    if(i<6)
    {
        id2[i]=i;
        pthread_create(&thread_teacher[i],NULL,teacher,(void*)&id2[i]);
    }
}

for (i=0;i<25;i++)
{
    pthread_join(thread_student[i],NULL);  
    if(i<6)
        pthread_join(thread_teacher[i],NULL);  
}
```